# I want to override InvoiceSender In magento2

Tags: magento2

I have to override InvoiceSender.php which path is Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender

i am not able to overirde its function :

```
<preference type="module\name\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override by following xml code in di.xml

```
<preference type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" for="module\name\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" />
```

You just interchanged the class name